# NoReverseMatch at /store/

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-project-architect

[main. html ,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IBJm.png) [store.html image ,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDcRg.png) [views.py image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNUBU.png) [url.py image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC2MY.png) I am building a e.com website using Django and python ..
there is little issue with main.html 
here im sharing the code and error screenshot
help me with these guys 
[error image i got stuck with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6o5i.png)

'''Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\vinay\Documents\project\ecom\store\templates\store\main.html, error at line 16

Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
6

```
<head>
7       <title>Ecom</title>
8   
9       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
10  
11      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
12  
13    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
14  
15    <script type="text/javascript">
16      var user = '{{request.user}}'
17  
18      function getToken(name) {
19          var cookieValue = null;
20          if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
21              var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
22              for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
23                  var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
24                  // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
25                  if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
26                      cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
 '''
```

Comment: Show us your **view.py** and **urls.py** too

Comment: check it again buddy , i edit the question with views.py nad urls.py image

Comment: show the full html page of store.html

Comment: ok i edit the image abouve there .. pls check

Comment: i thought problem is in main.html ?